# How to Rotate Paragraph?

Tags: java, android, itext

I know how to rotate cells in a table, but I just want to rotate a paragraph. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `Paragraph` to a `ColumnText` object, draw the `ColumnText` object to a `PdfTemplate` using the `go()` method. (Wrap the `PdfTemplate` in an `Image`) Add it to the page using a `PdfContentByte` using the `addTemplate()` method (or the `addImage()` method) defining the correct coordinates.

The parts marked with parenthesis are optional. Wraping the `PdfTemplate` inside an `Image` isn't necessary, but it can be more convenient as there are more ways to rotate an `Image` then there are to rotate a `PdfTemplate`.

There is yet another alternative: use `saveState()`, change the coordinate system with `concatCTM()`, add the `Paragraph` using `ColumnText`, use `restoreState()` to switch back to the original coordinate system.

In other words: there's more than one way to achieve what you want. It would help if you explained what you've tried and why it didn't work for you.